# communication b/w two application using socket in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sockets, communication

I am new in iPhone & want to perform communication b/w two application running on same device which exchange some string to one another using socket connection. I am using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` this function but it work with website URL but when I gave localhost it gives error.
Please suggest me how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most app don't run in background you would not be able to comunicate with them at all.
Only voip, navigation and audio apps can really run in de background.

Comment: the below link are very useful for create connection,isolved my prob.http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Listings/AppController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007321-AppController_h-DontLinkElementID_3